# multiplication question gcse maths

Tags: arithmetic

Please help.

What is $£3.99*114$ in long multiplication?

I have done the first part $3.99*4$, which is $15.96$. I am not sure about the rest.

Comment: You need $15.96$, when multiplying by 4 (units digit). Then your next row will end in a zero: 39.90, and last, your third row will end in two zeros...399.00. Now add $15.96 + 39.9+ 399$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Long_multiplication

Comment: Also, you may notice that $3.99 = 4 - 0.01$, and this means that $3.99 \times 114 = 4 \times 114 - 114 \times 0.01 = 456 - 1.14 = 454.86$.

Answer (score 0):

Because $3.99 = 4 - 0.01$, you can simply do:

$$\begin{align}
  (4 \cdot 114) - (0.01 \cdot 114) = \\
  456 - 1.14 = \\
  454.86
\end{align}$$
Therefore, $£3.99 \cdot 114 = £454.86$

This is an easier way of calculating Multiplications where $a_1$ ($3.99$ in this case) is a close to another number which is easier to multiply with $a_2$ ($114$ in this case):

$$\begin{align}
\underbrace {a_1}_{a_1\lt a_2} \cdot \underbrace{a_2}_{a_2 \gg a_1}=\\ 
(\lceil a_1 \rceil \cdot a_2)-((1-\{a_1\}) \cdot a_2)
\end{align}$$

Now what are those have square brackets? The bracket $\lceil x\rceil$ is the [Ceiling Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions). The squiggly bracket ($\{x\}$) is the [Fractional Part Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalPart.html).

**Example No.1:**

$$\begin{align}
15.87 \cdot 80= \\
(16 \cdot 80)-(0.13 \cdot 80)= \\
1280-10.4= \\
1269.6
\end{align}$$

Checking this on a calculator, does give us $1269.6$ indeed.

**Example No.2:**

$$\begin{align}
6.177 \cdot 97= \\
(7 \cdot 97)-(0.823 \cdot 97)= \\
679 - 79.831= \\
599.169
\end{align}$$

Even this one does equal to $599.169$ even when checked on a calculator.